# Nested list: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, list, loops, nested-lists

I have a nested list where I want to make some string operations. However, I got a this type of error. Does anyone know what does it mean?

```
def format_Well_Data(welldata):
       cor_welldata=[]
       for Well in welldata:
            pattern = re.search(r'\d{2}\/',Well)
            ii = pattern.start()
            well2 = Well[0:ii] + '  ' + Well[ii:]
            a=cor_welldata.append(well2)
        print(a)
 format_Well_Data([['AMV-10st102/13/19 4  954  3,968  '],
                  ['AMV-0201/24/19 6  3,078  1,303 ' ]])

The code should add 2 space at the start of the date(mm/dd/yy):
[['AMV-10st1  02/13/19 4  954  3,968  '],['AMV-02  01/24/19 6  3,078  1,303 ' ]]

However, i get this huge error message:
C:\Users\gogut\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\PTT\python.exe C:/APPL/DPI/PDF_reader/regextest_loop.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/APPL/DPI/PDF_reader/regextest_loop.py", line 14, in <module>
    ['AMV-0201/24/19 6  3,078  1,303 ' ]])
  File "C:/APPL/DPI/PDF_reader/regextest_loop.py", line 6, in format_Well_Data
    pattern = re.search(r'\d{2}\/',Well)
  File "C:\Users\gogut\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\PTT\lib\re.py", line 182, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: It seems that welldata is a list, therefore Well in your for-loop will also be a list; however, you can only search with a regular expression on a string. Maybe you want to put both strings in one list, instead of putting them alone in two lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you needed to return the data from the function, plus in your input, you have kepy the data in list of list. Below is solution without modifying your input data

```
import re
def format_Well_Data(welldata):
    cor_welldata=[]
    for Well in welldata:
           for wells in Well:
               pattern = re.search(r'\d{2}\/',wells)
               ii = pattern.start()
               well2 = wells[0:ii] + '  ' + wells[ii:]
               cor_welldata.append(well2)
    print(cor_welldata)
    return cor_welldata

format_Well_Data([['AMV-10st102/13/19 4  954  3,968  '],
                  ['AMV-0201/24/19 6  3,078  1,303 '] ])
```

otherwise if you don't to modify the current code then you can modify the input data as

from

`[['AMV-10st102/13/19 4  954  3,968  '],['AMV-0201/24/19 6  3,078  1,303 '] ]`

to `['AMV-10st102/13/19 4  954  3,968  ','AMV-0201/24/19 6  3,078  1,303 ' ]`

here is ittle imporve code

```
import re
def format_Well_Data(welldata):
    cor_welldata=[]
    for Well in welldata:
        patt = re.findall(r'\d\d/\d\d/\d\d',Well)
        str1 = Well.replace(patt[0], ' {}'.format(patt[0]))
        cor_welldata.append(str1)
    return cor_welldata

format_Well_Data(['AMV-10st102/13/19 4  954  3,968  ',
                  'AMV-0201/24/19 6  3,078  1,303 ' ])
"""
output

 ['AMV-10st1 02/13/19 4  954  3,968  ', 'AMV-02 01/24/19 6  3,078  1,303 ']

 """
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  The reason why i have nested list is that after it adds the space, I will use the .split() method to have 5 elements per list. Is there a way to  do it?

Comment: @Abumaru added a little improved version of this code. note check the input format, no need to woory regarding split

Comment: This solution worked quite good. Thank you for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

So two things.

First is that `re.search` expects a string, currently you  as supplying a list. Why do you need to include a list if there is only one element? if there are more just flatten them?

Second `.append` method does not return the appended list, it returns `None`. It is an inplace operation, so just print the list.

```
import re
def format_Well_Data(welldata):
    cor_welldata=[]
    for Well in welldata:
        pattern = re.search(r'\d{2}\/', Well)
        ii = pattern.start()
        well2 = Well[0:ii] + '  ' + Well[ii:]
        cor_welldata.append(well2)
    print(cor_welldata)

format_Well_Data(['AMV-10st102/13/19 4  954  3,968  ',
                  'AMV-0201/24/19 6  3,078  1,303 ' ])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['AMV-10st1  02/13/19 4  954  3,968  ', 'AMV-02  01/24/19 6  3,078  1,303 ']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  This is a nested list is because I plan to split each of these list into 5 elements. I used the re.search because I need the first regex found in each list. Is there any method in re. that could be used for list?. About .append you are right.